# how can I create a new data frame using exact rows from the old data frame in R Studio?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to select the exact rows from the old data frame and create a new one. I need to choose rows which contain paired numbers (as 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88 and 99). How can I do this?

I tried using filter:

```
paired1 <- filter(paired1$Var1=='22')
# Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
#  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

And with:

```
> with (paired1, sum (Freq[Var1 == '11' & '22']))
# Error in Var1 == "11" & "22" : 
#  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It should look more like `paired1 <- filter(paired1, Var1=='22')` assuming you are using `dplyr::filter`

Comment: You need `with(paired1, sum(Freq[Var1 %in% c(11, 22)]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two digit numbers:

```
paired1[paired1$var1 %in% seq(11, 99, 11),]
```

Comment: Corrected. Tks 

Answer (score 0):

We may use

```
subset(paired1, !nchar(sub("(\\d)\\1+", "", var1)))
```

-output

```
  var1
4   99
5   11
7   44
8  777
9  555
```

#### data

```
 paired1 <- data.frame(var1 = c(12, 13, 25, 99, 11, 42, 44, 777, 555, 3))
```